# Change dataset bound to Devexpress GridView?

Tags: devexpress

How do we bind 2 different datasets to the same DevExpress gridview. Depending on the value I pick it should populate either the first or the second datatset.

TU

Comment: Oops, do you mean ASP or WinForms or ..? My answers is for ASP. Please update the post appropriately and add the *appropriate* tags out of: `winforms`, `asp.net`, `aspxgridview` (and/or other).

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

Anyway, these are different approaches that will work:

1. Assign `grid.DataSource` in the Page/UserControl Load event; ensure to `Bind` it as required.
2. Assign `grid.DataSource` in the `OnDataBinding` event of the ASPxGridView and invoke `Bind` in Load event *as appropriate* (so the event is invoked).
3. Use a DataSource Control (I really like [GenericDataSourceControl](http://genericdatasource.codeplex.com/)) and then change what that returns (in GenericDataSourceControl there is a `OnExecuteSelect` function<sup>1</sup>). If set in the markup e.g. `DataSourceId=".."` then this will be bound automatically. `ObjectDataSource` and `LinqDataSource` also can also take declarative Parameters.

I prefer #3 for most cases. It is "bound late" which means that the state requires to determine what data-set to bind (e.g. in response to an event) has already been updated. Otherwise the event would have to re-Bind the grid, which is a wasted binding. As a bonus is also ensures that the ViewState is not cluttered/utilized.

Of course, at each one of these junctions, assign the "correct" dataset.

Another option, which is good if there are two disparate data-sets that have different column/sorting configurations is just to create *two* controls and then toggle the visibility between them (the real visibility, not just the client visibility). If a control is not visible, avoid binding data to it, as it is a wasted operation.

Happy coding!

---

<sup>1</sup> `LinqDataSource` and `ServerModeLinqDataSource` can also take a "select method", but I find the interface provided by GenericDataSource much easier to work with and is free of several "gotchas" when trying to update the Data Source. ObjectDataSource is just a PITA to deal with in GAC solutions and feels like a burden to use.

Comment: Thanks pst. I tried the object datasource and binding it to a select method at pageload. Doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @Giri You'll have to narrow down the issue more than that ;-) "doesn't work" can mean a whole lot of things; does it bind anything? the wrong thing? does the data disappear on a postback? *Update* the original question/post to include the approach used (and relevant source) as well as a description of what "doesn't work".

Comment: Not sure whether I am doing it right. I have an Object datasource which I am using for 3 different datasets(each dataset has different columns). I am using same devexpress and object datasource with different datasets.

Comment: it works. Is this right approach pst?. I haven't tried the other datasources.

Comment: @Giri There is nothing inherently *wrong* with that. Just make sure to write code that you can understand later ;-)

Comment: @pst-so much for checking with you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular condition depending on which the dataset is used to populate the aspxgridview?

You can just check that condition in your class file and then depending on that condition you can return a desired dataset.

Just pass one more parameter related to the condition to the method and return the accurate dataset and then bind it to the grid.